# $c_n = 1 + \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} +...+\frac{1}{n!}$ so prove $e - c_n \le \frac{1}{n! * n}$

Tags: calculus, inequality, summation

$c_n = 1 + \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} +...+\frac{1}{n!}$, so $e - c_n \le \frac{1}{n! * n}$

I absolutely have no idea how to solve it, could anyone tell me the approach?

Comment: Hint: recall that $e$ can be defined by a similar sum...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint.** Using the infinite summation representation of $e$, we have
$$ e - c_n = \sum_{r=0}^\infty \frac1{r!} - \sum_{r=0}^n \frac1{r!} = \sum_{r=n+1}^\infty \frac1{r!} = \frac1{n!}\left(\frac1{n+1} + \frac1{(n+1)(n+2)} + \cdots \right). $$
All that's left to do now is to show that the sum in brackets $()$ is $\le 1/n$.

---

As the OP pointed out in the comment below, we simply use that $n+r > n+1$ for $r > 1$, and hence
$$ \left(\frac1{n+1} + \frac1{(n+1)(n+2)} + \cdots \right) < \left( \frac1{n+1} + \frac1{(n+1)^2} + \frac1{(n+1)^3} \cdots \right) $$
$$ = \frac{\frac1{n+1}}{1-\frac1{n+1}} = \frac1{n+1-1} = \frac1n.$$

Comment: Just use the sum of decreasing geometric progression? It was really simple, Thanks!

Comment: Yep, exactly! Sorry if that slightly gave it away: I didn't expect you to get the bit that I left so quickly, but rather for me to give more advice; in my opinion, it's not that easy to spot immediately why $(\cdots) \le 1/n$, so congrats!

Answer (score 3):

The Taylor series for $e^x$ is given by

> $$e^x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}\tag 1$$

Using $(1)$ with $x=1$, we have

$$\begin{align}
e-c_n&=\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}\\\\
&\le\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}\left(1+\color{blue}{\underbrace{\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac1k}_{\text{Positive Terms}}}\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}\left(\frac{k}{k-1}-\frac1k\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\color{red}{\underbrace{\left(\frac{1}{(k-1)(k-1)!}-\frac{1}{k\,k!}\right)}_{\text{Telescoping Terms}}}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{n\,n!}
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: show that the sequence $c_n$ is strictly increasing and converges to $e$, then show that the sequence $c_n+\frac{1}{n!\cdot n}$ is strictly decreasing and also converges to $e$.

Comment: may be $c_n - \frac{1}{n!*n}$?

Comment: @Cheburek no. You want to show that $e\le c_n+\frac{1}{n!\cdot n}$, hence you need to study $c_n\mathbf{+}\frac{1}{n!\cdot n}$.

Comment: oh, I got it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We know

$$e = \frac{1}{0!} + \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} + \cdots$$

Fixing a positive integer $n$, let

\begin{align*}
x &= \frac{1}{0!} + \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n!}\\[4pt]
r &=  \frac{1}{(n+1)!} + \frac{1}{(n+2)!} + \frac{1}{(n+3)!} + \cdots\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Thus, we have

$$e = x + r$$

and we want to show

$$r < \frac{1}{n{(n!)}}$$

Then

\begin{align*}
r\, &=  \frac{1}{(n+1)!} + \frac{1}{(n+2)!} + \frac{1}{(n+3)!} + \cdots\\[4pt]
\implies\; (n+1)r\, &= \frac{n+1}{(n+1)!} + \frac{n+1}{(n+2)!} + \frac{n+1}{(n+3)!} + \cdots\\[4pt]
&< \frac{n+1}{(n+1)!} + \frac{n+2}{(n+2)!} + \frac{n+3}{(n+3)!} + \cdots\\[4pt]
&= \frac{1}{n!} + \frac{1}{(n+1)!} + \frac{1}{(n+2)!} + \cdots\\[4pt]
&= \frac{1}{n!} + r\\[16pt]
\text{Then}\;\,(n+1)r\, &< \frac{1}{n!} + r\\[4pt]
\implies\; nr\, &< \frac{1}{n!}\\[4pt]
\implies\;\;\;\, r\, &< \frac{1}{n{(n!)}}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

as required.